# git hook to trigger a Jenkins Job is not working

Tags: git, jenkins, githooks

If I execute 
    curl http://localhost:8081/Jenkins/job/test/build?delay=0sec
My Jenkins job get triggered but

I have created a `post-commit` file(.git/hook/post-commit) and added curl command as below

```
curl http://localhost:8081/Jenkins/job/test/build?delay=0sec
```

But when I push a commit my Jenkins job isn't get triggered. 
What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I push a commit

A `post-commit` is [client side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks).
It is triggered on commit, not on push. So make a new commit, and check if the job is triggered then.
(I assume the Jenkins job fetches the sources from your local git repo)

If the Jenkins job fetches from the server repo, then the `post-commit` hook has nothing to do with the job being triggered.

As the [OP Swapnil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1665592/swapnil) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448974/git-hook-to-trigger-a-jenkins-job-is-not-working/34449118?noredirect=1#comment56640337_34449118):

> My Poll SCM was `H/35 * * * *` so it may delayed for some time and I didn't noticed it.

Comment: Yep, I made a commit and then pushed it too.

 as my standalone `curl http://` working means from Jenkins side configuration everything is 'ok'

Comment: @Swapnil would the curl work from the client side? Because a pre-commit hook is executed on the client, not on the server to which you are pushing to.

Comment: Yep. I have executed it from client side

Comment: I'm sorry . I think I got the problem My Poll SCM was `H/35 * * * *` so it may delayed for some time and I didn't noticed it. :(

Comment: @Swapnil OK, I have included that in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: as these client side post-commit, it will only trigger build if post-commit added under .git/hooks.
I'm looking for generic solution which will trigger a Jenkins build for all users without asking him/her any local changes?

Comment: If your Jenkins only fetches sources from the server, then you need a post-receive hook, but that requires users to push their changes

Comment: As long as Jenkins fetches from the server, no amount of client-side hook would do anything. Any local changes would be ignored by the Jenkins job, no matter how it is triggered, because it would not fetch the changes from the client local clone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98901/discussion-between-swapnil-and-vonc).